Update Blank Values Until the Next Populated Row PHP/MySQL
I don't know how to explain it well, or how to even ask. Here's some of my data:
+------------+------------------------+
| Department | Product Number         |
+------------+------------------------+
| Decking    | Decking                |
|            | 11216CRC               |
|            | 114CRThted             |
|            | 114dg                  |
|            | 1212XPSL               |
|            | 1216crc                |
|            | 178dg                  |
| Drywall    | Drywall                |
|            | 10100Blockit           |
|            | 10125TyvekCW           |
|            | 10125TyvekDW           |
|            | 10150Bi                |
|            | 10178FS                |
| Poly       | Poly                   |
|            | Proplug                |
|            | Qkgravel               |
|            | QMCIG                  |
|            | QMCSP                  |
|            | rc1channel             |
|            | sac                    |
|            | Seamtape               |
|            | SilicaTitebondCL       |
+------------+------------------------+

I want to populate Department with 'Decking' until I get to Drywall. Then I want 'Drywall' until Poly, etc. etc.
I'm at the mercy of QuickBooks reports. I know, I'm trying to polish a turd. I thought maybe I could do it in MySQL, but I've already got a PHP scrip going that gets the data this far. I was thinking some kind of SELECT DISTINCT(Department) WHERE Department != ''; and start a loop that way. Not sure how to proceed though. I'm seeing case might work, but this is text and the examples I see are for numbers (and use <> signs).
There is probably some functionality I'm just not aware of. I've been doing this a while, but I'm self-taught.

You may have a bit if a problem here! As data, unless sorted, is returned in no specific order, you cannot guarantee the data will be returned in the order you have shown above

How did you generate that data in that order out of interest

Is the table you posted your actual MySQL table or something else? "I've already got a PHP scrip going that gets the data this far." - What does this mean, exactly? What is your starting point, if the table you posted is what you achieved with a PHP script?

I've got an excel file that QB spits out, with all sorts of wonkiness. The PHP I've written gets it into the DB in this format. The data is in the DB in the order I need it (what I posted). It's only sitting there long enough for me to cross reference it with another table.

Sounds like you need a basic "control break" implementation. While you loop over your records to create your output, you simply compare the department of the current record, to that of the previous one - and depending on whether they differ or are the same, you create output accordingly.
